# Does std::vector range constructor [start, end) copy or just reference the data?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, stdvector

I wonder if the range constructor of std::vector does copy the data, or does it just reference it?

Have a look at this example:

```
vector<int> getVector() {
    int arr[10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) arr[i] = i;
    return vector<int>(arr, arr+10);
}
```

Would this cause a bug (due to handing out a reference to the stack which is destroyed later) or is it fine, since it copies the data in the constructor?

## Edit #1

For clarification: I'm looking for a more or less official resource that points out, which of the following pseudo code implementations of the constructor are valid. I know the signature of the constructor is different... but, you should get the idea.

**Version A (just uses the given data internally)**

```
   template<typename T>
   class vector {
   private:
     T* data;
     int size;
   public:
     vector<T>(T* start, T* end) {
       data = start;
       size = (end - start);
     }
   };
```

**Version B (explicitly copies the data)**

```
   template<typename T>
   class vector {
   private:
     T* data;
     int size;
   public:
     vector<T>(T* start, T* end) {
       for(T* it = start; it < end; ++it) push_back(*it);
     }
   };
```

Comment: Version A is called `std::span`.

Answer (score 4):

Like all constructors of `std::vector<int>`, this copies the integers. The same holds for methods like `push_back` and `insert`

This is why `std::vector` actually has two template arguments. The second one is defaulted to `std::allocator`; it's the allocator used to allocate memory for the 10 integers (and perhaps a few more so that the vector can grow - see `capacity`)

[Edit]
The actual code is most like Version B, but probably similar to

```
template<typename T>
   class vector {
   private:
     T*     _Data = nullptr;
     size_t _Capacity = 0;
     size_t _Used = 0;
   public:
     vector<T>(T* start, T* end) {
       _Used = (end-begin);
       reserve(_Used); // Sets _Data, _Capacity
       std::uninitialized_copy(begin, end, _Data);
     }
   };
```

Comment: Well... there are constructors of `std::vector` which move instead of copying, but this isn't one of them.  (And for `int`, there's no difference between copy and move anyway).

Comment: Could you please leave some proof about this? Some pointer at an official document (std C++ reference or the like)...

Comment: Without the proof, this is just your opinion ;)

Comment: @SDwarfs: Are you wanting a standard citation?  I will add the language-lawyer tag to your question if you do.

Comment: The definition of the 'range' constructor is: `template< class InputIt >vector(InputIt first, InputIt last, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );` The first 2 arguments are ***values*** not ***references***!

Comment: @SDwarfs: The ultimate proof is the official standard ISO/IEC 14882:2017, but a fairly good summary can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: @Adrian: They are pointers passed by value.  OP's lifetime concern is a valid question.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Aah! I didn't actually spot that … you are right, of course. Maybe should have `return vector<int>(arr[0], arr[9]);` ?

Comment: @Adrian: No, the code is correct as written.  But OP's question cannot be answered just by reading the function signature as your comment believed.

Comment: Now I'm confused! But, then again, I'm still new to the Standard Library. But if it's a `vector<int>`, why give `int*` arguments?

Comment: @Adrian: Because that's what the caller has! (well, an `int arr[10]`, but its begin and end are `int*`).

Comment: @Adrian: Because `int*` allows the constructor to find every element it needs to make a copy of.  That's how a range constructor works.

Comment: Iterators, then?

Comment: @Adrian: That's why the range constructor is templated, so it can work with any sort of iterator, including iterators on ordinary arrays (which are bare pointers).  Notice that "pass an iterator by value" has the exact same potential lifetime problem as "pass a pointer by value".

Comment: @all: Added an "EDIT" to my post, to clarify what my question is all about.

Comment: @MSalters: The constructor would also need the allocator parameter in case of a "I just reference and copy if needed" (copy on write) implementation, where it would need the allocator in case of any changes made to the vector... Question: Where is this code sniped from? Any real implementation of std::vector?

Answer (score 4):

When in doubt, check the [reference](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.cons). The answer can be derived from Complexity section, although I'd agree there is no explicit confirmation:

> Complexity: Makes only N calls to the **copy constructor of T** (where N
>   is the distance between first and last) and no reallocations if
>   iterators first and last are of forward, bidirectional, or random
>   access categories. It makes order N calls to the copy constructor of T
>   and order logN reallocations if they are just input iterators.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard library is specified in a somewhat strange way.

It is specified saying what each method requires and what each method guarantees.  It is not specified as in "vector is a container of values that it owns", even though that is the *real* underlying abstraction here.

Formally, what you are doing is safe not because "the vector copies", but because none of the preconditions of any of the methods of std vector are violated in the copy of the std vector your function returns.

Similarly, the values are set to be certain ones because of the postconditions of the constructor, and then the pre and post conditions of the copy constructor and/or C++17 prvalue "elision" rules.

But trying to reason about C++ code in this way is madness.

A std::vector semantically is a regular type with value semantics that owns its own elements.  Regular types can be copied, and the copies behave sane even if the original object is destroyed.

Unless you make a `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>>` you are safe, and you are unsafe for the reference wrapper because you stored elements which are not regular value types.

Answer (score 0):

The vector can not be defined as a vector of references as for example `std::vector<int &>`. So the code is valid. The vector does not contain references to elements of the array. It creates new elements of the type `int` (as the template argument of the vector) not a vector of references.

Comment: It could be defined as a `std::vector<int*>` though.

Comment: Or `std::vector<ref<int>>`.   But the question is not about the vector element type, it's whether `std::vector` wraps access to existing data, ala `std::string_view`, or maintains its own copy.

Comment: @MSalters This has nothing common with the question and the definition of the vector in the code snippet in the question.

Comment: @BenVoigt My answer is correct. Your comments are irrelative and has nothing common with the question There is a code snippet in the question and the author bothers whether the result vector will contain references to the elements of the original array.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Your answer makes a correct statement (I didn't downvote) but misses the point (I didn't upvote).

Comment: As with any resizable container, `std::vector` has to point to data outside its own object (This can be trivially proven by noting that `sizeof(std::vector<int>)` is a constant).  The question is whether it points to the source data in-place, or makes a copy and points to the copy.  The latter is reality, but no amount of reasoning about the element type can get you there.

Comment: Whether vector accesses the data in-place or makes a copy is the entire question.